# Add unique object to array

Tags: ios, swift

I've read all about `Set`s and they don't fit the bill because my objects are not hashable (which is quite common).

I have a `Product` class

```
class Product: Object {

    dynamic var sku: String!
    dynamic var name: SomeUnhashableType!
    dynamic var weight: String!    
}

let uniqueProductArray = [productOne, productTwo, productThree]

uniqueProductArray.append(productOne)
```

I've read about using `contains`, `indexOf`, `filter`, etc. But they all use predicates and I'd like a non-predicate method.

What's the most elegant way of blocking duplicate objects from being appended to an array?

Comment: If your object is composed of hashable objects like String, why not just implement Hashable and use a set?  You can just concatenate your strings together and call hash on the result for your hash implementation.

Comment: @CharlesA. Edited cause thats not really the question, besides why not just use a set if they're hashable ?

Comment: @rayjohn: use the 'contains' for check the object already contains in the array the add the same.

Comment: @VineeshTP that does not work

Comment: @rayjohn: make sure the object properties are same . if not , it should taken as a different object.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what type isn't hashable?  Your implementation of `hash` and `isEqual:` can do whatever you want (within required limits).

Comment: The class above `does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`. Try and create a set out of it. @rmaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your class `Equatable` by adding that protocol to the definition and by implementing `==` for your class.  Then you can use `contains` without using the predicate version:

```
class Product: Object, Equatable {
    dynamic var sku: String!
    dynamic var name: String!
    dynamic var weight: String!
}

func == (lhs: Product, rhs: Product) -> Bool {
    return lhs.sku == rhs.sku && lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.weight == rhs.weight
}

let productOne = Product()
productOne.sku = "one"
productOne.name = "name"
productOne.weight = "heavy"

let productTwo = Product()
productTwo.sku = "two"
productTwo.name = "name"
productTwo.weight = "heavy"

let productThree = Product()
productThree.sku = "three"
productThree.name = "name"
productThree.weight = "heavy"

var uniqueProductArray = [productOne, productTwo]

if !uniqueProductArray.contains(productThree) {
    uniqueProductArray.append(productThree)
}
```